# Redis shards with multiple redis instances (each with cluster mode disabled) vs cluster mode enabled

Tags: redis

I'm trying to understand What is the difference between having multiple redis instances  (each with cluster mode disabled) vs using a redis instance with cluster mode enabled?

Answer (score 1):

When using Redis in single instance/standalone mode, sharding of the data (i.e. routing keys) needs to be done externally to the database (by the client or a proxy) as well as maintain high availability. When operating in cluster mode, Redis does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple Redis instances without cluster mode, your application will need to handle the sharding of data across the various instances. In cluster mode, Redis distributes key slot allocations amongst the various instances and Redis clients usually know how to read this information and read / write from the appropriate instances.

Also, when using publish / subscribe, when not using cluster mode, broadcasts won't go across various master nodes. Whereas in cluster mode, broadcasts will reach all the nodes in the cluster.